# Terraform does not recognize existing config files

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Today I wanted to move all my resources from default workspace to a production workspace to start working with prod and dev environment later. I used the $terraform state mv -state-out='./dev/terraform.tfstate' to move all resources to the dev environment. This was by accident because I wanted them in the prod environment. I must have been very overconfident because I deleted all state files in my main branch as well. Now I wanted to move them to the prod workspace, but I started getting errors the resources didn't exist in dev, because I deteled some state files. Luckily I had a backup statefile on github. However, now that I put this backup in my prod directory, I get my resources of the statefile when asking a state list, but when I use $terraform plan I get the following error:

Error: No configuration files

Plan requires configuration to be present. Planning without a configuration would mark   everything for destruction, which is normally not what is desired. If you would like to
destroy everything, run plan with the -destroy option. Otherwise, create a Terraform configuration file (.tf file) and try again.

This is the current file structure:

[image]

Feel free to ask questions as the problem was kinda hard to explain properly.

Comment: Terraform always runs in the context of the root module. Per the folder structure you have shared here there are no .tf or .tf.json files in the root module of your project structure. If you are writing env specific code you may probably either want to create a module.tf file ( which gets injected with the env folder as source by SED or something similar) or run terraform from the env directory.